# How to properly migrate your private and public keys

Tags: ssh, keys

I've bought a new laptop and copied my home folder from the older to the new machine. I've make sure that my .ssh folder was copied during the process, so I can see my keys inside that `/home/<my user>/.ssh`. However I can't can't access anything using those keys. For instance, when I try to `mvn package` an application, the remote Nexus repository does not grant me access.

Can anybody tell me how should I proceed to copy those keys properly?

Comment: Alternative option: Generate new private keys on the new machine.  This will force you to re-authorize everywhere, but it'll keep it easier to remember where you've authorized that key/machine.  Just an option.

Comment: @thomasrutter so this way I would need to re-share my pub key again. Did't I?

Comment: Did you make sure the .ssh directory's attributes were also copied (in particular, suitably restrictive access permissions for the directory itself and the key files)?

Comment: I'm not so sure. But I'm going to check it.

Answer (score 3):

First make sure that your keys you copied are not corrupted.
You can check and compare `md5sum` or `sha256sum` in both systems. It should be same for source and destination systems and each key you copied. If it is not case, Please copy again.

```
md5sum <filename> 

sha256sum <filename>
```

If checksum is same, You need to make sure that proper permissions and ownership are in place.

```
sudo chmod 700 ~/.ssh 
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
sudo chown user: -R  ~/.ssh/
```

Best way to copy keys by preserving permissions and ownership is rsync.
You can run below command in your new system. Here I assume that you are using in same network.

```
rsync user@{ip address or hostname of old system}/home/user/.ssh/* /home/user/.ssh/
```

In case user is different in your new system, you need to follow above step for fixing ownership.

Answer (score 1):

To transfer the keys to a new computer, you simply need to copy the `.ssh` subdirectory within your home directory across.  Permissions of that directory and its files are important, so for example `cp -a` or its equivalent would need to be used to copy files with their permissions.

Note that the root user's .ssh directory is at `/root/.ssh`, so any time something expects to be able to ssh as root, it's probably using the files in `/root/.ssh`, not your home directory.

Comment: What if there exists `~/.ssh` directory already on a new laptop? should it be removed before, or merged?

Comment: When copying files with permissions (`cp -a`), are there any requirements for a filesystem that has to be used to carry those files? maybe it is better to compress directory instead?

Comment: Existing .ssh dir can be replaced, it you accept that by doing so you won't keep existing ash settings for that user.

Comment: .ssh directories should only be used on filesystems that support Unix file permissions for security. If you need to transfer in an archive, tar is also able to preserve such permissions. Keep in mind you may need to chown after transfer.

Comment: Thanks for comments, would you mind extending your answer by explaining all the best practice for such migration?